# After installing Windows Server 2012 R2 and MsSQL no services are appearing

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, sql

After opening Sql Server Configuration Manager on my Windows Server 2012 R2 server running MsSQL, I have no services running. What did I do wrong?

[image]

Comment: Do they show up in the standard services window?

Comment: services.msc doesn't show anything related to Sql

Comment: check the setup going step-by-step how-to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0O_MCez5R0

Comment: @bluemunch As Raspberry mentioned, go over the setup again. It looks like you did something wrong / the setup was aborted. When you go over the setup again, make a note of whether or not it mentions there already being an instance.